# How to tell if a function is defined in php

Tags: php

How do I determine if a function is defined in php? 
I'd like to do something like:

```
if(! function_defined(money_format)) // function not defined on windows
{
      function money_format($str) { ... }
}
```

Is this possible in php?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the [`function_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) function to determine if a function has been defined.

Answer (score 6):

It's worth mentioning that you need to use [method_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) to see if an object has a particular method defined.